HOw to calculate the time difference in Minutes for a database?
Following 2 queries should calculate the difference in minutes, but one is correct and the other gives a wrong result. Is this a bug, or my bug?
SELECT FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),start_time))/60) AS minutes 

Above statement returns: 23  (correct)
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),start_time)) DIV 60 AS minutes 

Above statement returns:  -50339 (wrong)
Probably I prefer DIV, but it doesn't work properly.
I am using Server version: 10.11.8-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.24.04.1, in Ubuntu 24.

It would be nice if you added expected output. (Not able to reproduce, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/2r2pqUFy )

But the alias AS minutes in the middle of an expression is not where it is supposed to be ......

@Luuk  I think AS minutes is where it is supposed to be.  It's the = 23 and = 50339 that is wrong.  That's the expected output that you're requesting.  What we're missing to duplicate this is the value of start_time.

@mdfst13: statement2, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/bACyG3bt, seems to cause an error (also tested locally with MySQL9.0.1)

@Luuk  I can't see your fiddle when I click that link.  You might try SELECT FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),'2024-12-31 10:15:20')) / 60) AS minutes;

the fiddle just shows a working: SELECT 1=1; and a non-working (the reason for commenting it, so DBFIDDLE does not break): SELECT 1 as x =1;

Of course, SELECT 1 AS x =1 won't work because = 1 is wrong.  It's just SELECT 1 AS x.  Because 1 would be the expected output in the format of the question.  You were saying that AS is in the wrong place.  It isn't.  The = 1 should not be there.

Question need details or clarity about what is being done.  I do not want to guess what is wrong , and why it fails.

That's fine.  You don't have to guess.  I told you why you're getting an error (and what the expected output is).  If you want to say that you're getting an error, go ahead.  Just don't say that AS is in the wrong place.  It isn't.  The  = 23 (correct) is not valid syntax.  Personally, I find it obvious that the OP was saying "query= expected output (correct/wrong)".  If you don't, just say that.  Don't try to guess what the OP intends and debug that.  That just confuses the situation.  We still need the start_time value for an MCVE even if the format is fixed.

@Luuk & mdfst13 it is obvious to me that the "= 23" and "= -50399" are comments about the (syntactically correct) select statement that precedes them, just like the "(correct)" and "(wrong)" are

|@ysth: But, as msdfst13 told, it is still unclear what the value of start_time is.

TIMESTAMPDIFF() function
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, datetime_expr1, datetime_expr2)


Returns datetime_expr2 - datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and
datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions. One expression may
be a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a
datetime having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary. The unit for
the result (an integer) is given by the unit argument. The legal
values for unit are the same as those listed in the description of the
TIMESTAMPADD() function, i.e MICROSECOND, SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY,
WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.

PS. When precise result needs in rounding then decimal part is simply truncated.

I.e. you need in trivial
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, NOW()) ...


this is correct, except that you should always do date math on utc times.  so if start_time is stored as utc, timestampdiff(minute, start_time, utc_timestamp()), and if it is not, convert it first timestampdiff(minute, convert_tz(start_time, ?, '+00:00'), utc_timestamp())

I don't think that this is a bug.  See MariaDB SkySQL documentation for DIV:

Because the returned value is not rounded down, the result of x DIV y is not the same as FLOOR(x DIV y) when the resulting value is negative.

I.e. it is expected for FLOOR and DIV to give different results when the operand is negative.
You might try
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(start_time, NOW())) DIV 60 AS minutes

Or take the absolute value with ABS.
Also note that TIME_TO_SEC returns DOUBLE not INT.
DIV:

Incorrect results may occur for non-integer operands that exceed BIGINT range.

By contrast, FLOOR expects non-integer arguments.
